# Websphere keyset not get the latest key

Tags: java, websphere, keystore, keytool, keyset

I have a problem with a Websphere keyset. I create a keystore using a public key that was generated on another computer with keytool using this command:

```
keytool -import -noprompt -alias eeccstore -keystore eeccstore.jks -file D:\Keys\eecc_public.key -storepass password
```

After that, in Websphere Server I create the KeyStore as follows in the next image:

Keystore usages: Key set keystores

[Create keystore in Websphere Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tVVm.png)

I use the same password that I use to create the KeyStore with Keytool.

Then I create the keySet in WebSphere Server as follows in the next image:

[Create keyset in Websphere Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM7U6.png)

In my java code I use the keyset as follows:

```
KeySetHelper ksh = KeySetHelper.getInstance();
KeyPair key = (KeyPair)ksh.getLatestKeyForKeySet("eeccKeySet");
```

And the console shows me this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.ibm.ws.crypto.config.WSKeySet.getLatestKey(WSKeySet.java:257)
com.ibm.websphere.crypto.KeySetHelper.getLatestKeyForKeySet
```

I understand that the server can not find any key in the KeySet but I don't know what I could be doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Reggard!

Comment: Use IBM JDK to create the KeyStore. I had the same issue when I used IBM JDK, it went away.

Comment: Do you mean not use keytool to create KeyStore?

Comment: No,the keytool you use should be from IBM JDK not from Oracle/Sun/Open JDK.

Comment: I used the keytool from JDK inside IBM , still not working.

Comment: Can you get all the keyset for the group in the KeySetHelper. May be the name is incorrect. It is suffixing it with nodename or something

Comment: I use the method "getAllKeysForKeySet" that returns a map with all the keys and the size of that map is 0.

Comment: scope is at node level. One thing I can think of is your code is retrieving at cell level. You can change the cope to cell level and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching, I found a solution. Instead to access a KeySet, I access to KeyStore directly and get not the key, but the X509 certificate with wich can create the public key and use it to encrypt any text.

```
    char [] passch = password.toCharArray();

    com.ibm.crypto.provider.JavaKeyStore keystore = new JavaKeyStore();

    keystore.engineLoad(new FileInputStream(new File(pathKeyFileJKS)), null);
    KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry privKeyEntry =  (TrustedCertificateEntry) 
    keystore.engineGetEntry("eecc-KeyStore", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(passch)); 

    X509CertImpl cert = (X509CertImpl) privKeyEntry.getTrustedCertificate();

    cert.checkValidity();

    PublicKey publicKey  = cert.getPublicKey();
```

Where **password** variable contains the password that I use to create the eecc_public.key file, **pathKeyFileJKS** contains the path where create the jks file and **"eecc-KeyStore"** is the name that I use to create my keyStore in WebSphere Server.